# How to change the color of 4 pixels in an image, multiple times using opencv?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, pixel

I'm trying to write a program that will convert a 480x480 image into 240x240 quality, by taking the average color of 4 pixels and replacing all 4 with that average color. Then I repeat this for all 2x2 squares in the image. My program so far keeps replacing the entire image with the average color from the top left corner 4 squares, which is bgr [150, 138, 126]. Can someone help me see what I'm doing wrong?

```
def get_square(x1, x2, y1, y2):
    square = image[x1:x2, y1:y2]
    return square


def bgr_vals(img):
    b_vals, g_vals, r_vals = [], [], []
    x, y = 0, 0
    for i in range(4):
        b, g, r = image[x][y]
        b_vals.append(b)
        g_vals.append(g)
        r_vals.append(r)
        if y != 1:
            y += 1
        elif x == 0 and y == 1:
            x += 1
        elif x == 1 and y == 1:
            y -= 1
    return b_vals, g_vals, r_vals


def avg_color(bgr_vals):
    b_avg = np.average(bgr_vals[0])
    g_avg = np.average(bgr_vals[1])
    r_avg = np.average(bgr_vals[2])
    return [b_avg, g_avg, r_avg]


image = cv2.imread('src.jpg')

y1, y2 = 0, 2
for i in range(240):
    x1, x2 = 0, 2
    for i in range(240):
        patch = get_square(x1, x2, y1, y2)
        bgr_colors = bgr_vals(patch)
        color = avg_color(bgr_colors)
        image[x1:x2, y1:y2] = color
        x1 += 2
        x2 += 2
    y1 += 2
    y2 += 2
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your function `bgr_vals` you take argument `img` (which is the current patch), but within the method you inadvertently access `image` (the whole image) in this line:

```
b, g, r = image[x][y]
```

Your script works fine when you fix this typo.

Here are some tips for the future:

1. Images in OpenCV (and most libraries) are stored in row-first order, this means that you should write `image[y][x]` or `img[y][x]`. In your case it doesn't matter but in future work it might.
2. In general try to test your programs with non-square images, it is a common pitfall to only test with square-sized images
3. When you have cascaded loops, don't use the same variable name in the loop (you used i both times). Again, in your case it doesn't matter but as soon as you would use the value of `i` the confusion would start
4. Instead of increasing x, y within the loop you can use the loop variable directly, by getting a range with a step:

   ```
   for y in range(0, 480, 2):
       for x in range(0, 480, 2):
           …
   ```
5. Use array shape instead of hard-coding dimensions:

   ```
   for y in range(0, image.shape[0], 2):
       for x in range(0, image.shape[1], 2):
           …
   ```

Comment: If my answer is helpful, you might want to accept it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers